# Calculate angle to circle with avoiding obstacles

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, geometry, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a bot for a project called Ogar, an Agar.io server implementation written in Node.js.

This bot has an obstacle, a green spiky cell called a virus (see illustration). I need to program this bot to avoid that obstacle, but I'm with no luck. Since there are a lot of targets like in the illustration, it's based on updates.

[image: Illustration of what I want]

Here is the code that I ended up with until now.

```
BotPlayer.prototype.avoidObstacles = function(cell, angle) {
    // Sum up all of the vector angles of obstacles to cell and react against it
    var angleSum = 0;
    var collided = this.collisionFromList(cell, this.obstacles);
    if (collided.length == 0) return angle; // Not to return NaN

    for (var i = 0; i < collided.length; i++) {
        angleSum += this.angle(cell.position, collided[i].position);
    }

    angleSum /= collided.length; // Average out the angle sum

    // TODO: Find closest available edge
    angleSum += Math.PI / 2;

    return angle + angleSum;
};
```

This DOES work in most cases, but the bot sometimes completely ignores the obstacle (`this.collisionFromList(cell, this.obstacles);` is perfectly fine) and ends up literally going through it (explode into a lot of cells).

`BotPlayer.prototype` has a lot of useful functions for this kind of calculations. See [this link](http://pastebin.com/3HC96RtE).

I don't need any pathfinding squabbles, just this simple avoid measure.

Comment: If there are three equally spaced obstacles and your bot is heading towards the middle obstacle, wouldn't the angle that your calculating keep the bot going towards the middle obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative approach to what you are trying to do. The approach is to use attractors to describe entities in your system. Your "bot" is the `agent`, it has a position and it knows about other entities in the world and their attraction force. Say your destination has `+1 attraction` force and obstacles have `-X attraction` force, effectively repelling the "bot" (`agent`).

Here's a decision pseudo-code:

```
/**
* @param {Array.<{position:Vector2, attraction:Number}>} entities
*/
Agent.prototype.calculateDirectionVector = function(entities){
    var agentPosition = this.position;
    var result = new Vector2(0,0);

    entities.forEach(function(entity){
         //calculate separation between agent and entity
         var displacement = entity.position.clone().sub(agentPosition);
         //figure out distance between entities
         var distance = displacement.length();
         //dampen influence of attraction linearly with distance
         var influence = entity.attraction/distance;
         //produce force vector exerted by this entity on the agent
         var force = displacement.normalize().multiplyScalar(influence);
         //add up forces on the entity
         result.add(force);
    });

    //normalize the resulting vector
    result.normalize();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: An awesome solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's a big heuristic you made but if you wish to remain with this logic then consider taking into account the cartesian distance to the viruses, since you apparently have access to their position.

The function is `BotPlayer.prototype.getDist` or `BotPlayer.prototype.getAccDist`

You can use a threshold value `DIST_MIN` and a simple `if` or use a function like `angle/distance` (better) to reduce the impact the distant viruses have on the angle.